# For a locally ringed space $(X,\mathcal{O})$, is there a sheaf of ideals whose stalks are the max ideals of the stalks of $\mathcal{O}$?

Tags: sheaf-theory, ringed-spaces

For $X$ a locally ringed space with structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}$, for each $x \in X$
let $\mathcal{M}_x$ denote the max ideal of the stalk $\mathcal{O}_x$ of $\mathcal{O}$ at $x$.

In general, does there exist an $\mathcal{O}$-ideal sheaf $\mathcal{I} \subset \mathcal{O}$ on $X$,
whose stalk at each $x \in X$ is given by $\mathcal{I}_x = \mathcal{M}_x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: this answer originally erroneously said the answer was “yes”. In fact, the answer is “no”. Consider the sheaf of real-valued continuous functions on $X = \mathbb{R}$. We see that $\mathcal{O}_x$ consists of the germs of functions which vanish at $x$.

Consider $f(z) = z - x$. The germ of $f$ is in $M_x$.

If we had such an $I$, we could find some neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ such that $f|_U \in I(U)$. But we could find $y \neq x$, $y \in U$. Then we should have that the germ of $f$ is in $M_y$, but $f$ doesn’t vanish at $y$.

However, there is a “co-ideal” $C \subseteq \mathcal{O}$, defined by $C(U) = \{x \in \mathcal{O}(U) \mid x$ is a unit$\}$. The stalks $C_x$ are exactly $\mathcal{O}_x \setminus M_x$.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: May I ask: does this also work for e.g. a topological space $X$ with $\mathcal{O}$ the sheaf of real continuous functions? It seems that if $U\neq\emptyset$ then $I(U)$ consists of functions whose zero set is dense in $U$, hence (since points are closed in $\mathbb{R}$) the function is zero on all of $U$; therefore $I(U) = 0$? Is there an error in my reasoning somewhere?

Comment: You are correct. My original answer was wrong.

Comment: I see; may I ask: (1) Can we regard the "co-ideal" $C$ as a sheaf of Abelian groups, which is a "sub-monoid sheaf of an underlying multiplicative monoid sheaf" of $\mathcal{O}$? (2) Does the property I asked about hold for any nice classes of locally ringed spaces? E.g., schemes, or holomorphic complex manifolds? (Also, please feel free to let me know if this deserves its own separate question.)

Comment: (1) Yes, that is exactly right. (2) It doesn’t hold for the structure sheaf of $\mathbb{C}$ as a holomorphic complex manifold.

Comment: @IndraneelTambe2 However, I don’t mean to “define” a co-ideal as per your (1). In classical logic, co-ideal means the complement of an ideal. For sheaves, whose internal logic is not classical (except for a totally disconnected space), we have to clarify exactly what we mean by co-ideal. Thankfully, it turns out the right notion of co-ideal is a “coherent theory”; thus, if $\mathcal{C}$ is a co-ideal in the internal logic, then each $\mathcal{C}_x$ is a co-ideal. A local ring can be defined as a ring whose set of units is a co-ideal; this also works for defining a locally ringed space.